# One-loop approximation in chiral sigma models

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, 1pi-effective-action, sigma-models

Consider a principal chiral model $$S[g] = \frac{1}{4\pi\lambda^2}\int(|g^{-1}dg|^2) = \frac{1}{4\pi\lambda^2}\int(g^{-1}dg\wedge\star g^{-1}dg)  ,\tag{2.1}$$ where $g:\Sigma \rightarrow G $ is the so called principal chiral field (this theory is invariant under a $G_R\times G_L$ transformation). In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9902180), equation (2.6) is the action with a 1-loop correction, but I thought I could use $$\Gamma[g] = S[g] + tr\left[\ln S^{(2)}[g]  \right] + \cdots ,$$ where $$S^{(2)}[g] = \frac{\delta^2 S[h]}{\delta h(x) \delta h(y)}|_{h=g}.$$ But apparently it is not the case, it is a correction related to the cut-off $\Lambda$. I remember doing it in $\phi^4$ theory, considering Feynman diagrams, but I don't remember a systematic way of doing it, so I'm having troubles on this model. Can you help me to obtain the equation 2.6?

This correction is related to a correction on the G-invariant metric. If $\{t_a\}$ are the generator of the lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} = Lie(G)$, write $g(x)=e^{\alpha^a(x)t_a}$, the action becomes $$tr(g^{-1}dg\wedge\star g^{-1}dg) = g_{ab} \ d\alpha^a\wedge \star d\alpha^b$$ where $g_{ab}=tr(t_at_b)$ is the G-invariant metric. But the correction is: $$ \mu|tr(g^{-1}dg)|^2 = \mu \ tr(t_a)tr(t_b) \ d\alpha^a\wedge \star d\alpha^b$$. Therefore the correction is just a correction on the metric:

$$ tr(t_at_b) \longmapsto tr(t_at_b) + \mu tr(t_a)tr(t_b) $$

Comment: There is a contribution from the measure that is proportional to $\delta^d(0)$.